# User was denied access on the postgresql database (nodejs, prisma)

Tags: node.js, postgresql, prisma

I have these lines of code that try to use prisma with postgresql:

```
const { PrismaClient } = require('@prisma/client');
const prisma = new PrismaClient();

async function create()
{
    await prisma.user.create({

        data: {

            id: 0,
            email: "smth@smth.com",
            name: "john"
        }
    })
}

create()
    .catch(e => {

        console.log(e.message);
    })
    .finally(async () => {

        await prisma.$disconnect()
    })
```

And this thing then types this:
Invalid `prisma.user.create()` invocation in
/home/Mindw1n/Studying/NodeJsProjects/first/app.js:6:23

User `postgres` was denied access on the database `first.public`
Here's my schema.prisma:

```
generator client {
  provider = "prisma-client-js"
}

datasource db {
  provider = "postgresql"
  url      = "postgresql://postgres:pass@localhost:5432/first"
}

model User {

  id    Int     @id @default(autoincrement())
  email String  @unique
  name  String?
}
```

What do I do to connect node.js with prisma to postgresql?

Comment: url start with postgres not postgresql

Answer (score 1):

try to change url to this

```
url      = "postgres://postgres:pass@localhost:5432/first?schema=public"
```